# PS256 algorithm support for signatures in Java

Tags: java, jwt, java-security, nimbus-jose-jwt

According to the Java 12 security specs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#signature-algorithms) the RSASSA-PSS signature scheme should be supported (actually as of Java 11).
However, if I try to use a signature with PS256 algorithm in my JWT using e.g. the [nimbus jose+jwt](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt) library, then it doesn't work unless I use BouncyCastle.

```
        val signer = RSASSASigner(signKey)
        val jwsObject = JWSObject(
                JWSHeader.Builder(JWSAlgorithm.PS256)    // PS256 gives error;  RS256 will work
                        .keyID(signKeyId)
                        .build(),
                Payload(json)
        jwsObject.sign(signer)
```

This gives an error:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA256withRSAandMGF1 Signature not available
```

And indeed `JCASupport.isSupported(JWSAlgorithm.PS256)` is false

If I include BouncyCastle then it does work:

```
        Security.addProvider(BouncyCastleProviderSingleton.getInstance())
        JCASupport.isSupported(JWSAlgorithm.PS256) == true
```

I would have thought that BouncyCastle is not necessary anymore in Java 12 (I'm actually using Kotlin 1.3 with Java 12 and Spring Boot 2.2 and com.nimbusds 8.4 to be precise). 
I would like to be independent from BouncyCastle.

What am I missing?

Comment: For Java 11+ the alogirhtm identifier seems to be `RSASSA-PSS` and not `SHA256withRSAandMGF1`. Also after inspecting the source code of this library it they use `SHA256withRSAandMGF1` identifier so they are bound to BouncyCastle. I am afraid as for this version of your library you have no choice but use BC as provider.

Comment: I have now tried also a different library, namely jsonwebtoken on https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt but I get the same error, even though the documentation in here also states that you JDK11 should also work.

Comment: any luck @user1120821 ?

Comment: @Samir yes, in JWTT it was solved, see https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/issues/542 (not sure about nimbus though)